# how to get tags by using tag-it jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-plugins, tag-it

I am using tag-it jquery plugin for my work.
I want to get tags which i was entered in the text area but i got empty string. here is my code

```
<?
    $simple_tags = array('c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript', 'asp', 'ruby', 'python', 'c', 'scala', 'groovy', 'haskell', 'perl', 'erlang', 'apl', 'cobol', 'go', 'lua');
?>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var sampleTags = <?php echo json_encode($simple_tags); ?>; 
            $('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
                availableTags: sampleTags,
                // This will make Tag-it submit a single form value, as a comma-delimited field.
                singleField: true
            });
        });
        function show()
        {
            console.log($('#singleFieldTags').val());
        }
    </script>

<div id="wrapper"> 

    <div id="content">
        <form>
            <ul id="singleFieldTags"></ul>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="show()">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `ul` elements don't have a `value`. Try the [`assignedTags`](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown#assignedtags) method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would say that you make the tags as string. Secondly use an input element rather than the ul in order to get the values.

Your code would become something like the following.

Remember to link it to your js function alert so that you could see the output value.

Let me know if it works as I have worked with this plugin in the past.

```
<?php 

    $simple_tags = "'c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript', 'asp', 'ruby', 'python', 'c', 'scala', 'groovy', 'haskell', 'perl', 'erlang', 'apl', 'cobol', 'go', 'lua'";

?>    

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
      var sampleTags = [<?php echo $simple_tags; ?>];
      $("#singleFieldTags").tagit({
          availableTags: sampleTags
    });
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="singleFieldTags"/>
```